# Zuul Response filter getting blocked for sometime intermittently

Tags: netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

We are using zuul 2.1.6 without eureka and we got the response back form down stream API but it's getting blocked for some reason in the response/outbound filter sometimes (not all the time). It's happening intermittently and the CPU also not used much during these times.
What could be the root cause? Anyone faced a scenario like this?
Thank in advance for any suggestions..

Below is how the response filter looks like

```
@OverRide
HttpResponseMessage apply(HttpResponseMessage response) {
SessionContext context = response.getContext()
if (SEND_RESPONSE_HEADERS.get()) {
    Headers headers = response.getHeaders()

    StatusCategory statusCategory = StatusCategoryUtils.getStatusCategory(response)
    if (statusCategory != null) {
        headers.set(X_ZUUL_STATUS, statusCategory.name())
    }

    RequestAttempts attempts = RequestAttempts.getFromSessionContext(response.getContext())
    String headerStr = ""
    if (attempts != null) {
        headerStr = attempts.toString()
    }
    headers.set(X_ZUUL_PROXY_ATTEMPTS, headerStr)

    headers.set(X_ZUUL, "zuul")
    headers.set(X_ZUUL_INSTANCE, System.getenv("EC2_INSTANCE_ID") ?: "unknown")
    headers.set(CONNECTION, KEEP_ALIVE)
    headers.set(X_ZUUL_FILTER_EXECUTION_STATUS, context.getFilterExecutionSummary().toString())
    headers.set(X_ORIGINATING_URL, response.getInboundRequest().reconstructURI())

    log.info("status:"+ attempts.get(0).getStatus()+" duration:"+ attempts.get(0).getDuration())

    if (response.getStatus() >= 400 && context.getError() != null) {
        Throwable error = context.getError()
        headers.set(X_ZUUL_ERROR_CAUSE,
                error instanceof ZuulException ? ((ZuulException) error).getErrorCause() :     "UNKNOWN_CAUSE")
    }

    if (response.getStatus() >= 400) {
        log.info("Passport: {}", CurrentPassport.fromSessionContext(context))
    }
}

if (context.debugRequest()) {
    Debug.getRequestDebug(context).forEach({ s -> log.info("REQ_DEBUG: " + s) })
    Debug.getRoutingDebug(context).forEach({ s -> log.info("ZUUL_DEBUG: " + s) })
}

return response
```

}

}

Let's say The status log which is after the headers.set got logged at 28-11-23 19:30:10 and the passport log, which is after few lines getting logged at 28-11-23 19:30:20. it is taking/blocked for 10 secs there.

Tried increasing the ribbon read timeout and netty thread counts, still seeing the issue.